# « Central limit theorem » se traduit-il bien par « théorème de la limite centrée » ?

Tags: traduction, mathématiques

[*Central limit theorem*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_central_limite) se traduit-il par *Théorème de la limite centrée* ou *Théorème de la limite centrale* ? je n'aime pas trop cette traduction, même si elle est mieux que la traduction utilisée par Wikipédia *Théorème centrale limite* :). Bref, quels sont les usages et qu'est-ce qui les motive ? Est-ce la limite qui est centrée ou le théorème qui est central ?

Comment: Sauf que ça s'appelle “théorème centrale limite”, point. Bon c'est un peu plus compliqué (voir les réponses) mais au final peu importe ce que ça veut dire ou ce qui traduit le mieux quoi, c'est une notion courante qui a un nom établi en français et seul l'usage devrait compter il me semble.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A l'origine il s'agit d'un théorème énoncé et démontré par Abraham de Moivre (un français) mais je ne sais pas comment il l'avait nommé.

Le terme *central limit theorem* est une traduction de l'allemand *zentraler Grenzwertsatz* utilisé par le mathématicien allemand Polya. Ce qui est central c'est le théorème dans le sens qu'il est très important en probabilité ; le terme de limite fait référence à l'objet sur lequel porte le théorème.

Beaucoup d'auteurs français utilisent *théorème de la limite centrale* mais une traduction de l'allemand suggère plutôt de l'appeler *théorème central sur la limite*. *Théorème de la limite centrale* est français mais désigne mal les mathématiques qui se cachent derrière. Une traduction proposée et argumentée par Walter Appel (*Mathématiques pour la physique*, éd 3, p.486) est *théorème central limite*. L'avantage de ce choix est d'insister sur le fait que le *central* porte sur le théorème et non sur la limite. Pour ma part j'utilise cette expression, qui bien que correcte mathématiquement n'est pas très française, je trouve ! Il faudrait sans doute mieux utiliser *théorème central de/sur la limite* mais c'est sans doute trop long.

En conclusion, s'il faut faire un choix entre les deux traductions ce sera : **théorème central limite**.

Comment: Une solution est d'utiliser la même approche que pour l'abbréviation UTC, qui ne veut rien dire dans les deux langues en contention. Donc: central théorème limite =]

Comment: Théorème central limite est la forme actuellement parlée et écrite. Je n'ai jamais entendu un francophone utiliser une autre expression de vive voix.

Answer (score 3):

J'ai fait petite une étude pour voir :

- théorème de la limite centrale : 50 800 résultats sur Google ;
- théorème central limite : 15 600 résultats.

Donc les gens préfèrent la première traduction.

Comment: Bof. Le Google hit, je n'y crois pas trop dans ce cas. Fais le au moins sur Scholar.

Comment: Scholar configuré pour "n'afficher que les résultats en français" a une préférence pour le théorème de la limite centrale : 508 occurrences contre 43 pour le théorème central limite. Donc les chercheurs préfèrent la première traduction. C'est plus joli, mais c'est tout.

Comment: @Cygal J'ai [504](http://imgur.com/8Vrmu) pour ["théorème de la limite centrale"](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=%22th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me+de+la+limite+centrale%22&btnG=Search&lr=lang_fr&as_sdt=1%2C5&as_ylo=&as_vis=0) et [1050](http://imgur.com/tZ7Vq) pour ["théorème central limite"](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=%22th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me+central+limite%22&btnG=Search&lr=lang_fr&as_sdt=1%2C5&as_ylo=&as_vis=0). C'était quoi, ta recherche ?

Comment: ["théorème centrale limite"](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q="théorème+centrale+limite"&lr=lang_fr), au temps pour moi.